# if the metric $d_1$ is complete, and $\lim_{n \to \infty} d_1(x_n,x)=0$ iff $\lim_{n \to \infty} d_2(x_n,x)=0$, is $d_2$ complete?

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

two metrics $d_1, d_2$ on $X$, 
For all $x_n$  and $x$ from $X$ it holds :
$\lim_{n \to \infty} d_1(x_n,x)=0$ iff $\lim_{n \to \infty} d_2(x_n,x)=0$

Is it true that $(X, d_1)$ complete implies that  $(X, d_2)$ complete ?

Comment: I edited your post, so as to format it, but you should use mathJax in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Let $X=[1,\infty)$. Define $$d_1(x,y)=|x-y|,\quad d_2(x,y)=\left|\frac 1x-\frac 1y\right|.$$Then $d_1$ is certainly complete, but $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence with respect to $d_2$ if $x_n=n$.